# PictureBox paint event executing twice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, managed-c++

I added a picture box to a WinForms form and added a paint event. When I debug it, I see that the paint event is called twice.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why would this be surprising? I'd expect to see the paint event called many times, once per paint cycle.

Comment: Your either doing c++ or c#, which one is it?

Comment: I dont understand, why it is calling twice when the program just opening? For example; in my paint event handler, if I draw an image to the pic box the user can see that it is drawn twice. I wont to abort it.

Comment: I would suggest posting you paint event code. You may be trying to do too much, or maybe you are doing something in the event to trigger then second paint event. If you are getting a flickering effect you can always try turning `DoubleBuffering` on for the control/form

Answer (score 4):

The picture box control is a relatively loose wrapper around Windows paint cycles and the `WM_PAINT` event.

The `WM_PAINT` event is a queued message that the system places in your applications message queue whenever it deems that a window's drawing surface is invalid. This can happen for many reasons:

- Another window is dragged over the top of your window (although modern windows use buffering to alleviate this).
- You invalidate the window by calling `Invalidate` which ultimately calls the Win32 `InvalidateRect` function.
- System wide theme preferences changed.
- Etc. etc.

So, the natural conclusion of this is that your picture box paint handler needs to be written under the assumption that it will be called multiple times.

Comment: How to write paint handler like that? I'm drawing graph, one draw is pretty slow, so I dont want it to be redrawn immediately after first draw. Could I somehow find out what cause redraw call and decide whether I want to really redraw?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: As I said, Im drawing big graph and one draw takes about 10seconds, then there is always immediately called second redraw, because of second redraw, app looks like frozen, and system is drawing again on already drawn paint, so its unnecessary. I tried to return immediately from my paint to see if Im causing second repaint, but was called anyway..

Comment: I've just found that, removing this `panel_topology.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel_topology_Paint);` helped. Visual studio must defined my handler somewhere I didnt know about :)

Comment: Should not tak 10 seconds to draw the graph. Fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The paint event is fired on every redraw which is quite often. The code in your paint event handler should be able to cope with it being called n-times.